# Deploy uniswap v3 subgraph to local graph-node error: indexing handleIncreaseLiquidity Token#get:decimals with message: "Value is not a BigInt"

Tags: node.js, graphql, ethereum, hyperledger, uniswap

**Hi, I' m tring to deploy this subgraph to a local graph node that is connected to a local ethereum node on the goerli network.**

The **OS** is xubuntu v21.10 .

The **node** is hyperledger besu v22.1.2.

The **graph-node** version is 0.26.0 and run with docker-compose .

**In the subgraph.yaml i have removed this:**

graft:

```
  base: 

  block:
```

Because i haven't this subgraph deployed local, i changed the network to goerli and the start block to '7011478'.
For the deploy I use these commands:
**yarn**

**yarn codegen**

**yarn create-local**

**yarn deploy-local**

After deployment and after some blocks have been indexed I get this **error**:

ERRO Handler skipped due to execution failure, error: Mapping aborted at ~**lib/@graphprotocol/graph-ts/index.ts, line 811, column 4**, with message: **Value is not a BigInt**. wasm backtrace:        0: 0x25f8 - !**src/types/schema/Token#get:decimals**       1: 0x2611 - !~**lib/@graphprotocol/graph-ts/index/BigDecimal#constructor**     2: 0x29e3 - !src/mappings/
position-manager/**handleDecreaseLiquidity**    , handler: handleIncreaseLiquidity, block_hash: 0x41ea414f5ef6ef940b2b0557d0f403f8b2c1c32c22616dd4d45e0cf3a81dc8d0, block_number: 7011552, sgd: 1, subgraph_id:
QmNwsfk3kJi8zzmBDVEiCGqioRnpyZM1iSTPPVYVNyDsop, component: SubgraphInstanceManager

**With which version of graph-node was this subgraph deployed?**

**Does anyone have any idea what it could be?**

Comment: do you find the answer?
I have the exact issue for Arbitrum

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/UniSwap/comments/vauykv/error_indexing_handleincreaseliquidity_on_a_local/ => I guess this is also you :D

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in your handler. Check the code in `handleDecreaseLiquidity`.
It seems like you have a field defined as BigInt in your schema but you are assigning a BigDecimal to that field in your handler.

If you post your schema and handler code it will be possible to debug further.